# How to select multiple checkbox in Reactjs

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a option list where I want to select multiple checkbox but not able to do that, what's wrong with this code?

[Sandbox URL](https://codesandbox.io/s/blissful-bessie-6pooc3?file=/src/App.js)

Comment: Please always supply relevant code in your questions. If it is only supplied in an external sandbox, the question is liable to break in the future, when the sandbox is deleted, or the sandbox site goes offline.

Comment: I believe Stack Overflow now has a "snippets" system, so code can be made to run in the question itself, and thus in some cases an external sandbox is unnecessary.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

follow your requirements, you can change handleCheckboxQuestionInput to:

```
const handleCheckboxQuestionInput = (e) => {
    const answer = e.target.value;
    setSelectedAnswers((prevAnswers) => {
      if(prevAnswers.includes(answer)) {
        return prevAnswers.filter(e => e !== answer)
      } else {
        return [...prevAnswers, answer]
      }
    });
  };
```

and at input element change to:

```
<input
    type="checkbox"
    name={currentQuestion}
    value={option}
    key={i}
    checked={selectedAnswers.includes(option)}
    onChange={(e) => handleCheckboxQuestionInput(e)}
 />
```

hopeful that will help you